# Prevent child process writing shared memory?

Tags: linux, shared-memory, child-process

My process makes a shared memory section as runtime stack(Co's stack run on the shared memory). Thus my process can restore the runtime in case it core dump.

But I meet a problem. I don't want child-process to write anything to stack memory which is actually the super-process's stack after a fork. I knew I just need to make the memory copy-on-write to the child process. So I must declare this shared memory to private, but this makes changes to it from super-process lost after a core dump restart.

Is there any mechanism in Linux that makes a shared memory does not inherit to the child process, but only to that process explicit attach to it? Maybe a mmap flag? or a system call to override the copy-on-write configuration to a specific memory section?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to simply unmap or remap, or use mprotect, etc. after the fork?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there are situations where the fork is invoked by other library or system() I can not control the next operation. Actually I don’t want the shared memory used by any other process but my process’s next starting after core dump. @Hasturkun

Comment: You might be able to make use of `pthread_atfork` to handle the library cases (though that's only for `fork`, and not `system()` etc, AFAICT, though those tend to call `exec` quite soon which will likely unmap your shared memory anyway). Also won't do much about `clone`. I think if you really distrust potential children, you could fork yourself first, clean up, then let those run.

Comment: Thanks. Fork for myself at starting is impossible because I'm a CO-Library(which supports runtime restore after a core-dump) the business invokes my functions. My solution is to tell the business code do not to invoke `fork` or `system` but use a helper object which is forked at the beginning. But the library I can not control.